# Remove multiple html5 data-attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

So jquery api says the following:

> Removing data from jQuery's internal .data() cache does not effect any HTML5 data- attributes in a document; use .removeAttr() to remove those.

I have no problem removing a single data-attribute.

```
<a title="title" data-loremIpsum="Ipsum" data-loremDolor="Dolor"></a>
$('a').removeAttr('data-loremipsum');
```

---

The question is, how can I remove multiple data-attributes?

More details:

1. The starting point is that I have *multiple* ( let's say.. 60 )
   different data-attributes and I want to remove all of them.
2. Preferred way would be to target only those data-attributes that contain the word `lorem`. In this case `lorem` is always the first word. (or second if you count `data-`)
3. Also I'd like to keep all the other attributes intact

Comment: I think you will have to use the .attr() function to loop through all the attributes and remove if name contains specific string..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
// Fetch an array of all the data
var data = $("a").data(),
    i;
// Fetch all the key-names
var keys = $.map(data , function(value, key) { return key; });
// Loop through the keys, remove the attribute if the key contains "lorem".
for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i].indexOf('lorem') != -1) {
        $("a").removeAttr("data-" + keys[i]);
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gpqh5/

Comment: What if the attribute contains keys with additional dash separators such as data-lorem-ipsum="azbqat"? 

In the example above, those would not be removed.

Answer (score 5):

In [my jQuery placeholder plugin](http://mths.be/placeholder), I’m using the following to get all the attributes for a given element:

```
function args(elem) {
    // Return an object of element attributes
    var newAttrs = {},
        rinlinejQuery = /^jQuery\d+$/;
    $.each(elem.attributes, function(i, attr) {
        if (attr.specified && !rinlinejQuery.test(attr.name)) {
            newAttrs[attr.name] = attr.value;
        }
    });
    return newAttrs;
}
```

Note that `elem` is an element object, not a jQuery object.

You could easily tweak this, to get only `data-*` attribute names:

```
function getDataAttributeNames(elem) {
    var names = [],
        rDataAttr = /^data-/;
    $.each(elem.attributes, function(i, attr) {
        if (attr.specified && rDataAttr.test(attr.name)) {
            names.push(attr.name);
        }
    });
    return names;
}
```

You could then loop over the resulting array, and call `removeAttr()` for each item on the element.

Here’s a simple jQuery plugin that should do the trick:

```
$.fn.removeAttrs = function(regex) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            names = [];
        $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr) {
                if (attr.specified && regex.test(attr.name)) {
                        $this.removeAttr(attr.name);
                }
        });
    });
};

// remove all data-* attributes
$('#my-element').removeAttrs(/^data-/);
// remove all data-lorem* attributes
$('#my-element').removeAttrs(/^data-lorem/);
```

Comment: Note that this code is entirely untested (except the snippet from my plugin) but it should give you an idea of how to solve it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS below clears *all* data attributes. If you want to add some `if` logic to remove a subset of data attributes, it should be trivial to add that functionality to the below JavaScript.

```
function clearDataAttributes(el){
    if (el.hasAttributes()) {
        var attrs = el.attributes;
        var thisAttributeString = "";
        for(var i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            thisAttributeString = attrs[i].name + "-" + attrs[i].value;
            el.removeAttribute(thisAttributeString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, shouldn't it simply do `el.removeAttribute(attrs[i].name);` without using `thisAttributeString`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post answer as well, as it took me some time to make working version from Mathias post.

The problems I had was that SVG needs extra-care, there are little nuances(jQuery doesn't like it), but here is the code that should work for SVG as well:

```
$.fn.removeAttrs = function(attrToRemove, attrValue) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this)[0];
        var toBeRemoved = [];
        _.each($this.attributes, function (attr) {
            if (attr && attr.name.indexOf(attrToRemove) >= 0) {
                if (attrValue && attr.value !== attrValue)
                    return;

                toBeRemoved.push(attr.name);
            }
        });

        _.each(toBeRemoved, function(attrName) {
            $this.removeAttribute(attrName);
        });
    });
};
```

note that it is using underscore, but you could replace _.each with $.each I believe.

Usage:

```
svgMapClone
    .find('*')
    .addBack()
    .removeAttrs('svg-')
    .removeAttrs('context-')
    .removeAttrs('class', '')
    .removeAttrs('data-target')
    .removeAttrs('dynamic-cursor')
    .removeAttrs('transform', 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)')
    .removeAttrs("ng-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all of the data attributes of specific element and filter for index of a sub-string.

**REMOVE_ATTR**
I used the [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)  method, but you *may* be able to use the [.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/) method depending on how the data-attribute was created. Substitute or combine as you see fit.

```
 $.each($('div').data(), function (i) {
      var dataName = i, criteria = "lorem";
      if (dataName.indexOf(criteria) >= 0) { 
          $('div').removeAttr("data-"+dataName);
      }
 });
```

**SET NULL**
You can also optionally set the data-attribute to null depending on your business logic.

```
$.each($('div').data(), function (i) {
    var dataName = i, criteria = "lorem";
    if (dataName.indexOf(criteria) >= 0) { 
       $('div').data(dataName, "");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery method **removeData()**

jQuery site states:

> The .removeData() method allows us to remove values that were
>   previously set using .data(). When called with the name of a key,
>   .removeData() deletes that particular value. When called with no
>   arguments, .removeData() removes all values.

The key part here is:

> When called with no
>   arguments, .removeData() removes all values.

https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Answer (score -3):

Sadly it is not possible in jQuery to select attribute names that starts with a given value (for attribute values it is possible).

The easiest solution i came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-loremIpsum], [data-loremDolor]').each(function(index, value) {
        $(this).removeAttr('data-loremIpsum')
               .removeAttr('data-loremDolor');
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nP64/) (Make sure to look up the html source code after you clicked run)